# MongoDb C# driver is slow even in simple queries

Tags: c#, .net, database, mongodb

I need to retrieve all documents from a collection in mongodb. There's nothing special about the query, I just need all the documents to be returned.

The statuses of my collection are:

```
{
    "ns" : "MyDb.MyCollection",
    "size" : 206553804,
    "count" : 123663,
    "avgObjSize" : 1670,
    "storageSize" : 30953472,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1122304,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 1122304
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

In my C # function, I wrote the following code:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

var database = client.GetDatabase("MyDb");

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");

var documents = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
```

The problem is that in the line of the function find() takes about 60 seconds to return all documents and this is hindering my application performance. This simple query in other collections is also taking longer than usual to return something. The database is running locally.

I'm using:

- MongoDb 3.6.10;
- MongoDb.Driver 2.7.0
- .NET Framework 4.7
- Windows 10

Also, my machine is a 7th generation i7 with 16gb ram and 256 SSD. Queries take the same time when the application is on the production server.

Is there anything I can do to improve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there is no reason to Find All documents, can you limit the results to specific count? or use a filter ?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what kind of application needs to display 123k documents to the user? i.e. why do you need to retrieve all documents from the db in a single batch? what's the use case here?

Comment: @jawad I want to retrieve all documents. Retrieving only a few documents or using a filter is not an option in my case.

Comment: @RyanGunner It is an application that gives insights related to the supply chain of large brazilian companies. I need this data to build a dashboard for customers.

Comment: I would still suggest looking into Pagination. Trying to get the entire data in one go will take some time

Comment: Dashboards usually show summarized data, not 123,000 records.   I suggest you restructure the query to use aggregations to summarize and return the datapoints the dashboard really need rather than have the dashboard take details and summarize them.

Comment: The laws of physics (not MongoDB) say it's going to take a finite amount of time to read 100k documents from one block of memory to another block of memory. I would recommend you look at the dashboard and see if a subset of documents would do the job. Or try a `$sample` aggregation operator.